# Django the Note instance doesn't keep the images when form is submitting?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

implementing below code, I achieved this 1 Note model with many Images. the `uploading_views` is working fine. Multiple Uploads at the same time, with same Choose File button, & all save together.

Now i want to perform the `PostUpdateViews` for updating the Note. i also get the note data into the form instead images. The code of `PostUpdateViews` function is only update note instance `[title, text]` instead images. when i submit the form the form is create new images it's not changing  the old images.
how can i get Note related images into the Note form and update it. I would be grateful for any help.

**Models**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Images(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='files/', null=True, blank=True)
```

**Views**

```
def uploading_views(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NoteFullForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            note_obj = Note.objects.create(title=title, text=text)  # create will create as well as save too in db.
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
                Images.objects.create(note=note_obj, image=f)
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        form = NoteFullForm()
    return render(request, 'uploading.html', {'form': form})


def PostUpdateViews(request, id):
    note = Note.objects.get(id=id)
    form = NoteFullForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=note)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']
        note_obj = Note.objects.create(title=title, text=text)
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            Images.objects.create(note=note_obj, image=f)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/up/update/27/')
    else:
        form = NoteFullForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'uploading.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Is the intent to update a single image (like I had image A before but I want to replace that with image B) or is the goal to replace all the images?

Comment: yes i want to replace all the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the old instances of Images, also you are creating a new instance of Note for some reason! change it like so:

```
def PostUpdateViews(request, id):
    note = Note.objects.get(id=id)
    form = NoteFullForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=note)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']
        Images.objects.filter(note=note).delete() # Deleting old images
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            Images.objects.create(note=note, image=f)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/up/update/27/')
    else:
        form = NoteFullForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'uploading.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you want to do is find the `Image` objects associated with the particular `Note` you are trying to update and delete them.

Try:

```py
def PostUpdateViews(request, id):
    note = Note.objects.get(id=id)
    form = NoteFullForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=note)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Find all images associated with that particular Note
        image_set = Image.objects.filter(note=note)
        # Delete them before creating your new ones
        image_set.delete()

        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']
        note_obj = Note.objects.create(title=title, text=text)
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            Images.objects.create(note=note_obj, image=f)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/up/update/27/')
    else:
        form = NoteFullForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'uploading.html', {'form': form})
```

Also note that this is not going to update the old `Note` instances. It is going to create new ones. If you want to update the existing `Note` instance (with a new text and title) you should do something like:

```py
def PostUpdateViews(request, id):
    note = Note.objects.get(id=id)
    form = NoteFullForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=note)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Find all images associated with that particular Note
        image_set = Image.objects.filter(note=note)
        # Delete them before creating your new ones
        image_set.delete()

        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']

        # Update existing Note object instead of creating new one
        note.title = title
        note.text = text
        note.save()

        for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            # Use existing note object as foreign key for images
            Images.objects.create(note=note, image=f)

        return redirect('/up/update/27/')
    else:
        form = NoteFullForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'uploading.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Don't know if you know this but if you instantiate the form with an instance of the model you can simply call `form.save()` To update the model instance. :)

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. I find it helpful to explicitly write out what I'm updating for readability but that is redundant to instantiate the form with the note instance and then just manually update the note! Good catch